# Network watcher traffic flow azure monitoring

Tags: azure

New to network watcher in azure and just wanted to know if it can watch flow to and from a resource group, as well as to and from a vm?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is right, what you want is Monitor network connections. You could check this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/connection-monitor).

[image]

More information about Network Watcher you could check this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-monitoring-overview).